# Convert date/time in certain format with VBA

Tags: vba, excel

SO, this is some kind of example of what I am trying to do, VBA is doing like loop, opening some files, filter them and saves them..but thing is I would like to Specify date format in `DD.MM.YYYY hh:mm`  in Column A (complete) as output. I dont know how to do that, tried something but it was always wrong output...

```
Sub Convert()

    Dim FileSystem As Object
    Dim HostFolder As String

    ' Folder with systems
    HostFolder = "C:\Users\MirzaV\Desktop\Converter"

    Set FileSystem = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    DoFolder FileSystem.GetFolder(HostFolder)

End Sub
```

```
Sub DoFolder(Folder)
    Dim Workbook
    Dim SubFolder
    Dim date_test As Integer

    For Each SubFolder In Folder.SubFolders
        DoFolder SubFolder
    Next
    Dim File
    For Each File In Folder.Files
        ' Operate on each file
        Set Workbook = Workbooks.Open(File)

        'MsgBox (Workbook.FileFormat)

        If Workbook.FileFormat = -4158 Then
            Set Workbook = Workbook.ActiveSheet
            Workbook.Columns("D:R").EntireColumn.Delete
            Workbook.Columns("F:H").EntireColumn.Delete
            Workbook.Rows("1:2").Delete
            Dim FLDR_NAME As String
            FLDR_NAME = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path & "_converted"
            Dim fso As Object
            Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
            FLDR_NAME = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path
            FLDR_NAME = Replace(FLDR_NAME, "Converter", "Converter_Converted")
            If Not fso.FolderExists(FLDR_NAME) Then
                fso.CreateFolder (FLDR_NAME)
            End If
            Dim newFileName As String
            newFileName = FLDR_NAME & "\" & Workbook.Name & "_converted.txt"
            Workbook.SaveAs Filename:=newFileName


            'Close + Save
            Application.ActiveWorkbook.Close
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Where do you try to format the value? I would think you could use `Worksheetfunction.Text()`, no?  Or [VBA's built in String Format()](https://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/format_string.php) (also [here](https://www.excelfunctions.net/vba-format-function.html))

Comment: I tried with some copy/paste vba*s, but it didnt work properly... in that code I didnt include anything, just asked for help.  And I am not so good in vba, mostly I am taking from examples and trying to make something. Unfortunately.

Comment: Getting this : 8/17/2018 17:30    but I need 17.08.2018 17:30

Comment: Where is the code where you attempt to apply a format to column A? It seems like you have everything else here.

Comment: As I wrote...I don"t have it in code, after I run this code up, I got at the end of the day almost all fitered but only in Column A is the date in wrong format, and I wanna just before save-ing my file to have it converted into proper format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you've gotten all your rows and columns deleted, you can format column A like this:

```
Workbook.Columns("A").NumberFormat = "dd.mm.yyyy hh:mm"
```

Comment: This seems to work, but will check in the office on excel 2013.., at home I got 2016 and it usually opens and runs almost all, but on the work is always struggle , I do not know how. Will write in 2 h again!

Comment: It is me again, just tested here in the Office, works as charm!! Thank you Bob, it was simple as a day for you but saved me stress since last 2 days and would continue, because formats here in Germany are different, and programs makes different...makes big mess on the Charts or not possible to make it clear!!!  regards

Comment: @M1rzÄ You're very welcome. If you find that it's the answer, please accept it as such so people who are looking for the same answer will know that there is one here.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to give your date that format then you should do this

```
new_date = Format(date_var, "dd.mm.yyyy hh:mm")
```

Where `date_var` would be the date you are getting with the code (but we cannot see).